# Why does this django query return a tuple instead of the object?

Tags: django

I'm working on a project and found a bug which makes no sense to me. In these lines:

```
customer = Customer.objects.get_or_create(phone=from_number)
store = Store.objects.get(phone=to_number)
logging.info("CUSTOMER TYPE: {}".format(type(customer)))
logging.info("STORE TYPE: {}".format(type(customer)))
```

In the logs, the customer type says `CUSTOMER TYPE: <class 'tuple'>`, but the store type says `STORE TYPE: <class 'orders.models.Store'>`.

Both classes are in the same project and app, both are included in the same way (`from orders.models import Customer, Store`)

If it's of any help, the classes are these:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Nombre")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13, verbose_name="Teléfono")
    last_location = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Ultima ubicación")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Store(models.Model):
    service_hours = models.ForeignKey(ServiceHours, related_name="stores", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Nombre")
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13, verbose_name="Celular")
    enabled = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Dirección")
    dialogflow_id_project = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, default='pedidoswhatsapp-hcujca')
    file_settings_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, default='pedidos_dialogflow.json')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I don't get how the code would be taking the customer as a tuple. Any help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [**`.get_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) *always* returns a 2-tuple. A 2-tuple where the first item contains the object obtained (or constructed), and the second a boolean that indicates if it was created. This is specified in the documentation as:

> Returns a **tuple of `(object, created)`**, where `object` is the retrieved or created object and **`created` is a boolean** specifying **whether a new object was created**.

You can for example use *iterable unpacking* to get rid of the second boolean:

```
customer, __ = Customer.objects.get_or_create(phone=from_number)
```

[**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) on the other hand only returns the object (or raises an error if the query returns zero, or more than one element). There is also no need to return a boolean as well, since `.get(…)` will not create an object in case it does not exists.

Comment: Yes, I was about to answer my own question, that just slipped my mind. I will accept this as the answer when I'm allowed to, thanks!